# Happy pi day, everyone!

Tags: mathematics, wordplay

A baker is working a batch of dough.  He shapes it into a cylinder of height *a* and radius *z*.

**What will the baker make from this volume of dough?**

Comment: Title must be "Hap'pi day everyone" :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

He will make

> pizza.

The volume is

> Height times pi times the square of the radius, i.e. $pi * z * z * a$.

Comment: Wow that was quick!  Well done.  I will award the tick at the end of the day.

Comment: either that or pizaz!

Answer (score 18):

> Old joke - he's making pizza: pi * z * z * a

Comment: Very quick!  The old ones are the best ones!  I will award the tick at the end of the day.

Comment: Got ninja'd *again*?! >:(

Comment: @user477343 - Meh. Can't help it if there are people who can type faster than me... :)

Comment: Well, I don't think it's fair: it's about how fast you get the answer, not how fast you can *type* the answer... but since it's online, what can you do? Hence, it's unfair. So you know what I do for those who get ninja'd? ;)

Comment: @user477343 gonna wait and post my answer a few seconds late in the future just so that you give me a bounty ;P

Comment: @Brandon_J Hahaha, well that may work ;)

Comment: Jeff, congratulations on the $\boxed{\color{blue}{+100}}$ rep bounty, and a further congratulations on getting past 3k rep! :D

Answer (score 14):

While I agree with Jeff's answer, it also depends on the actual height and radius used.

> If a > 1" (perhaps even 1/2" because dough rises with yeast assuming a typical p*i*z*z*a batter), the p*i*z*z*a will be way too thick to resemble pizza.  Typically crusts (before baking) are way less than a < 1/2", though I've never tried a thick-pan crust.
> Also if z < 3", the pizza will be far too small to be a realistic pizza.  (Mini-pizzas at z = 2"?)

But given realistic values of a and z, I certainly agree with Jeff's answer.

(I'd add a comment instead to Jeff's answer, but reputation '50' is required for that.) 
:(

Happy pi day.

Comment: Even with a big tall cylinder of dough, he'll still make pizza because that will be the volume he'll make.

Answer (score 9):

> Volume $V$ of a cylinder of given height $h$ and radius $r$ is given by $V = \pi r^2 h$.

Therefore,

> the volume of said object is $\pi z^2 a$. But since today is pi day, I assume the correct answer is pizza.

:)